# How to copy files from a dataset column

Tags: directory, sas, macros, copy

I looking for copy a list of image from a directory into an other one.
For that I have the names of the images with the extension in a dataset (column "image_name")

[image]

I have already create a code that detect the files in a directory.
But I want to :

- Detect only the files when the names is in the column "imagename"
- Copy the list of images in an other folder

```
%let path="C:/Users/Morisseau1/DSPP/Donnees/image_test_o_sas/";
    
    %let indir=&path;
    %let nfiles=0;
    filename indir "&indir";
    data _filenames1(where=(index(filename,'.')));
     format filename $45. ;
     did=dopen('indir');
     do i=1 to dnum(did);
     filename=dread(did,i);
    output;
     end;
     rc=dclose(did);
     keep filename ;
    run;
    data filenames;
    set _filenames1;
    ord=_n_;
    run;
    proc sql noprint;
    select max(ord) into: maxord
    from filenames;
    quit;
```

Comment: SO tip... When creating a fixed text block, use three back tick (`\``) instead of three single quote (`'`)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the values in the data set instead of the directory scan.
The DATA step is an implicit loop.

```
  data _null_;
    length source destin $8; /* dynamic filerefs to be assigned by filename() */

    retain indir "<source-folder>" outdir "<destin-folder>";
    
    set instructions; /* data set containing image_name values */

    if fileexist (indir || '/' || image_name) then do;
      rc = filename (source, indir || '/' || image_name);
      rc = filename (destin, outdir || '/' || image_name);
      rc = fcopy (source, destin);
      if rc ne 0 then do;
        msg = sysmsg();
        putlog msg;
      end;
      rc = filename (source); call missing (source);
      rc = filename (destin); call missing (destin);
    end;
  run;
```

Comment: Thank you @Richard. Sorry for the error in the fixed block. Maybe it's a misunderstanding but I don't understand how your code can goes inside my code. Because SAS need to browse each line of my data set to catch the name of the file. Also I forgot to say that the name of my dataset is called X_TEST. don't know how to loop inside it before copying in the folder

Comment: Thank you it works. I just had to add a "set" instructions to give the name of the dataset

Comment: Awesome, I updated answer to have the missing `SET` statement

Comment: Would you need different rc variables to check that properly?

Comment: @Reeza, not really.  Fully robust code would check for rc=0 at the filename() and if not display the sysmsg(), and continue if fileref could not be established.  Totally robust code is a bit much and might help in a situation where memory or resource handles are bumping up against limits of session or system.